# Eclipse CDT build error

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Hey guys i've worked on eclipse IDE for java till now.i want to switch to C++ now.i added a plugin to that eclipse from update.When i wrote a sample program am getting a question mark before the header inclusion and when iam trying to build the project its saying that error :

* Build of configuration Debug for project Helloworld *
*(make: not found)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to bet you're on Windows and need a C++ compiler (including a 'make' utility).  See http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO.

Comment: ...or you can install MS Visual Studio and use the compiler made by them. Their IDE is great for debugging, but that's about it.

Comment: Visual Studio also supports x64 compilation, which to my knowledge, mingw does not.